# PWA Not Listed as Installed App on Android

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA which I have loaded on Windows 10 and Android 12 platforms. On both platforms, I get an install prompt upon initial download. The PWA works offline on both platforms. Both platforms are opening a dedicated window with no address bar.

On Windows, the PWA is listed as an installed app in Control Panel > Programs and Features. However, on Android, the PWA is not listed as an installed app in Settings > Apps.

Is this normal or is something wrong with the PWA's configuration?